# How to check if an image is B&W in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an UIImage that shows a photo downloaded from the net.
I would like to know away to programmatically discover if the image is in B&W or Color.

Comment: Welcome to the world of Core Image.  Take a seat, your GPU will be on fire momentarily.

Comment: What if it's [a colour picture of a black & white world](http://i.imgur.com/4rPGp.jpg)?

Comment: @ACB An image could still be considered black and white (greyscale) even with a full RGB color space.

Comment: Before asking a question here, you should do some research and attempt to find a solution on your own. If you're stuck, list what you've tried or where you're having problems.

Comment: @rmaddy, Thanks. Removed my comment. Didn't think that it was misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you dont mind a computing intensive task and you want the job done, check pixel per pixel the image.

The idea is to check if all R G B channels for each single pixels are similar, for example a pixel with RGB 45-45-45 is a gray, and also 43-42-44 because all channels are close to each other. I'm looking that every channel has a similar value (i am using a threshold of 10 but it's just random, you have to do some tests)

As soon you have enought pixels that are above your threshold you can break the loop an flag the image as colored

the code is not tested, is just an idea, and hopefully without leaks.

```
// load image 
CGImageRef imageRef = yourUIImage.CGImage
CFDataRef cfData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(imageRef));
NSData * data = (NSData *) cfData;
char *pixels = (char *)[data bytes];

const int threshold = 10; //define a gray threshold

for(int i = 0; i < [data length]; i += 4)
{
    Byte red = pixels[i];
    Byte green = pixels[i+1];
    Byte blue = pixels[i+2];

    //check if a single channel is too far from the average value. 
    //greys have RGB values very close to each other
    int average = (red+green+blue)/3; 
    if( abs(average - red) >= threshold ||
        abs(average - green) >= threshold ||
        abs(average - blue) >= threshold )
    { 
        //possibly its a colored pixel.. !! 
    }
}
CFRelease(cfData);
```